# How I can install application like .exe or dll file by java code

Tags: java

How to install silently application in windows by java code. I have downloaded the file from server but need to install also on a single click.
How can I achieve this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correct you want to install a third application from your java application. All you can do is below (this is for exe.. not sure about dll, I do not think you can run them). That should run the installable exe. But it will install or not that depends upon how that software works.. an give it a try.. But this is not recommended

```
     public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your installable exe");
    proc.waitFor(); //Wait for it to finish
    System.exit(0);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `ProcessBuilder` would generally be preferred as it solves many of the issues associated with `Process`; You should also make sure you're reading the `Process`'s `InputStream` as not doing so can cause some programs to stall

Comment: I am not able to install application silently.

Comment: You may not able to do it silently because the operating system will not let you do that.. User need to know what is getting installed in their machine.. You can just start the process and let user handle the rest

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
String command = "C:\\setup.exe";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c "+command);
```

[read more.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

To run batch file try:

Add this to your batch file:

```
@echo off
C:\Windows\notepad.exe yourpath\omt.txt
```

In your java program:

```
String filePath = "C:/yourbatpath.bat";
try {     
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);     
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[read this to get in depth idea.](http://omtlab.com/java-how-to-run-exe-file-and-batch-file-using-java-program/)

Comment: well done. Im happy if you got anything in my answer!.